# Declaration Error in c

Tags: c, pointers, declaration

I was writing a program to read files.
And i have been having runtime error depending on whether or not i place `int i` in the third line of main function.

I see no reason that for it have an effect on my program. But it does. 
So why is it happening?
And, at least in principle, should we not be able to declare variables wherever we desire?

here is my code

**Got Answer**

MORAL of the STORY: Always initialize your pointers before using them.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char read_char(FILE ** fp);    

int main()
    {
        char * str;
        str = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char));

        FILE * f;
        // int i                     <---------Problem here

        f = fopen("txt.txt", "r");

        *str = read_char(&f);
        putchar(*str);

        return 0;
    }


    char read_char(FILE ** fp)
    {
        char * c;
        c = malloc(sizeof(char));

        if ((*fp) == NULL)
        {
             printf("Error accessing file");
             exit(0);
        }

        (*c) = getc((*fp));
        return((*c));
    }
```

Comment: you missed the `;` it should be `int i;`

Comment: Also, `read_char` needs to be declared or defined *before* it's used.

Comment: It must be a compile error, not runtime one

Comment: FWIW you should show the compile error ... if it was complaining about the `f = fopen(...` line, looking back to check the previous line was correctly terminated is always sensible.

Comment: You have a memory leak as well.

Comment: additionally `*str = read_char(&f);` is wrong `str` contains a garbage address you are assigning into that address.

Comment: With adding the semi-colon the compiler may give you a warning as you are not using `i`

Comment: I wrote an answer to this question but deleted it after taking a closer look at the code. The problem is this: you don't know how any of the programming features you are using actually work. You are merely guessing. When programming, you must understand 100% of what your own code does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have defined

```
 char * str;
```

and you have use it

```
*str = read_char(&f);
```

and `str` is not yet pointed to a memory space

the `*str` means the content of the first byte in the memory space (which the `str` pointer is pointing on) will filled with the returned char value from `read_char()` function

In fact what you did is an undefined behaviour. So Adding the i definition give a kind of behaviour. Remove i definition give another kind of behaviour

here after your code fixed

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char read_char(FILE *fp);    

int main()
{
    char * str = malloc(sizeof(char)); 
    FILE * f;
    int i;

    f = fopen("txt.txt", "r");

    *str = read_char(f);
    putchar(*str);

    return 0;
}


char read_char(FILE * fp)
{
    char c;

    if (fp == NULL)
    {
         printf("Error accessing file");
         exit(0);
    }

    c = getc(fp);
    return c;
}
```

Comment: give him a correct way that will be helpful for OP

Comment: Adding memory allocation does not seem to help

Comment: you have to fix some points in your code

Comment: I fixed your code in my answer

Comment: @MohamedKALLEL Well Kallel .. Put a `free(str)` at the end of main too it will ne nice.

Answer (score 1):

NEVER create pointer variables without setting them to NULL. Use:

```
char* str = NULL;
FILE* f = NULL;
```

And you'll find your error in no time.

Answer to your question is: you were writing into unallocated memory, so anything may happen. Weird things like this one are often.

As a side note, there is no point in using pointer here. Use:

```
char someChar;
...

someChar = read_char(...
```

Same goes for read_char:

```
char  c;
...
c = getc((*fp));
```

Comment: add also in you answer, that `*str = read_char(&f);`  is wrong without allocating memory..

Comment: Sorry but that did not work

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan well, I want him to set the pointer to NULL and see the program crash for himself.

Comment: @user1990721 yes, it was intended to not work and give you exact location of the error. Try the version without `char* str;` if you want immediate results.

Comment: @Agent_L yes that is good! but it would be good it you suggest a way to correct code.

Comment: @user1990721 I've edited, try it now.

Comment: @Agent_L I used NULL assignment. But still having this problem

Comment: @user1990721 with NULL it should crash right away with a message telling you the exact location of the problem. Are you using any debugger?

Comment: @Agent_L You were correct I should not give him code.. +1 to your answer that I can see to are still helping him

Answer (score 1):

As I commented to your question: 
additionally `*str = read_char(&f);` is wrong `str` contains a garbage address you are assigning into that address.

I have corrected your code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char* read_char(FILE ** fp);    

int main()
    {
        char *str;
        FILE * f;
        int i;   

        f = fopen("txt.txt", "r");

        str = read_char(&f);
        putchar(*str); 
        free(str);

        printf("\n");
        return 0;
    }


    char* read_char(FILE ** fp)
    {
        char * c;
        c = malloc(sizeof(char));

        if ((*fp) == NULL)
        {
             printf("Error accessing file");
             exit(0);
        }

        (*c) = getc((*fp));
        return(c);
    }
```

- Additionally you do not need `int i;` its `warning: unused variable ‘i’` .
- second don't return `*c` from `read_char(FILE ** fp)` instead return address and assign to `str` to do this I have changed the return type of `read_char(FILE ** fp)`:

  `char* read_char(FILE ** fp);`
- Also you have allocated memory for read char dynamically using malloc in `char* read_char(FILE ** fp);` free that memory in `main()`

Not your code working fine:

your input file:

```
:~$ cat txt.txt
yourname
```

code compile and run:

```
:~$ gcc code.c -Wall -o code
code.c: In function ‘main’:
code.c:10: warning: unused variable ‘i’
:~$ ./code 
y
```

Comment: This seems to be working.... Thanks a lot. I still do not understand what was wrong with my implementation. Is not returning (*c) and (c) functionally equivalent given that you appropriately handle it from where you call it?

Comment: ok by returning `*c` you were returning value not address, `*c` is value and `c` is *address of char*. and both are not same

Comment: It's a very bad thing to give working replacement instead of answer. He still has no idea what was wrong with his code. He still doesn't know how to debug and he'll still need help with simplest problems in the future.

Comment: i do understand that...Still even if i was returning a value i was assign it to (*str). According to me that should work. I dont see why not...

Comment: @Agent_L Actually you are correct....I did bit wrong! but I added enough information to make him understood thing and I am still connected with OP.

Comment: @user1990721 Exactly. you were assigning to `*str`, which means "something str points to" without even setting `str` to point to something. That's what NULLs are for to make it crash right away instead of sometimes working and sometimes not, as addition of `int ` did.

Comment: @user1990721 assigning to `*str` you were assigning to  an garbage address. that is default value of `str`. And leads to undefined behaviour. as [**Lundin commented in your answer**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14401223/declaration-error-in-c/14401622#comment20037700_14401223)

Comment: @Agent_L Oh i get it does it mean the uninitialized pointers can not be used for pointing to values?

Comment: @user1990721 No, as one author said "Pointer is like pistol. If you don't point it at target, it just lays there, pointing at something random. Then you pull the trigger and something gets hit, but you'll never know what." And NULL is like a barrel plug. Trying to use NULL pointer blows right in your face and you know where the problem is.

Comment: Oh thanks man i get it now. You are a saviour.

Comment: @Agent_L you got good compliment from OP that is the big think...

Answer (score 0):

Semi-colon.

```
int i
```

should be

```
int i;
```

Comment: -1 he said **"...And i have been having runtime error depending on whether or not i place..."**

Comment: @MohamedKALLEL A declaration error is a compiler error.